# Text not correctly converted libreoffice docx to pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, libreoffice, alpine-linux, doc

I have a big problem converting doc/docx to pdf.
I created a file conversion API with Symfony. I mainly work on ubuntu, and never had any problems.
But I have to migrate from Ubuntu to Alpine. And there comes the tragedy.

Basically, the text is converted into strange characters.
example result conversion

Image pdf converted

[image: 1]

I have searched far and wide, but nothing that is relevant to my problem. The api is working and there are no problems there, but libreoffice does not work as it should.

I am open to any advice you could give me.

Comment: It seems as if the used font is not present. You might be able to install it.

Comment: But it is really strange, I have no special characters apart from plain text, and all special characters have been added correctly. I'll try deleting and re-installing.
I'll see if I can find info on the character installation.
Thank you @thebusybee

Comment: Did you check the used font in the docx file? What does LibreOffice show if you open it in the GUI on Alpine? And how does the pdf (converted on Alpine) look like if opened on Ubuntu? Are you aware that you can embed fonts (check the conversion options)?

Comment: files are displayed corectually on ubuntu (local and remote), for alpine I only have the docker file

Comment: when api returns the converted file, it gives me this result on all plain text carraers

Comment: I downloaded both files (original docx and pdf) from apline... the docx displayed without errors, but the pdf with only plain text and as in the example above

Comment: code integrated in api:       soffice --headless 
 --convert-to pdf 'path/file.docx'  --outdir 'path/file'

Comment: In the end I did that by separating the api converter, creating a second docker container in parallel.

This solution works.

I thank you all very much for giving me many suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpine and a too minimalised os verion.
I created a classic php-apache docker container in parallel, which solved my problem.

Now everything works without any problems.

Executing a call to api rest of the converter, integrated as a promise in the main api.